# How to display all available routes on an embed map with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to know if it's possible to show all the available routes using public services (like trains or buses) between two points and be able to choose one to see more details in an embedded map using the Google Maps API (Embed of Javascript) like using the Google maps website itself ([Example](https://www.google.es/maps/dir/Utrecht+Centraal,+Stationshal,+Hoog-Catharijne+CS+en+Leidseveer,+Utrecht,+Pa%C3%AFsos+Baixos/Concordiastraat,+Utrecht,+Pa%C3%AFsos+Baixos/@52.0917628,5.1022163,14.5z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c66f5d6556b979:0xb88d703d634c4d6e!2m2!1d5.1101691!2d52.0893191!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c66f6d791d1c53:0x448d692110ae252b!2m2!1d5.0983096!2d52.0996097!3e3?hl=ca)).

As far as I concern, I can only embed a map with just one specific route, or a global map, but not one with all of them and let the user choose which one prefer.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible. You just need to create new `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` for every route.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [directions in the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Directions). To use it, you need to create an object of type `DirectionsService` and call `DirectionsService.route()` to initiate a request to the Directions service, passing it a `DirectionsRequest` object literal containing the input terms and a callback method to execute upon receipt of the response.

The DirectionsRequest object contains the following fields:

```
{
origin: LatLng | String | google.maps.Place,
destination: LatLng | String | google.maps.Place,
travelMode: TravelMode,
transitOptions: TransitOptions,
drivingOptions: DrivingOptions,
unitSystem: UnitSystem,
waypoints[]: DirectionsWaypoint,
optimizeWaypoints: Boolean,
provideRouteAlternatives: Boolean,
avoidHighways: Boolean,
avoidTolls: Boolean,
region: String
}
```

For the [`TransitOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#TransitOptions) you can specify here what modes you are using.

- google.maps.TransitMode.BUS indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by bus.
- google.maps.TransitMode.RAIL indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by train, tram, light rail, and subway.
- google.maps.TransitMode.SUBWAY indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by subway.
- google.maps.TransitMode.TRAIN indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by train.
- google.maps.TransitMode.TRAM indicates that the calculated route should prefer travel by tram and light rail.

For the `provideRouteAlternatives`, when set to true it specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server.